# Efficient way to check if value is changed in a static variable in Java

Tags: java

I have a for loop that constantly fetches the latest size of a static set in an interface class and I believe it's consuming too much CPU resource as my fans start running pretty soon when it's executed.

Code:

```
for (int noOfPositions = exchange.positions.size(); noOfPositions != 0; noOfPositions = exchange.positions.size()) {
    if (noOfPositions > totalTrades) {
         // some logic       
    }
}
```

The static variable is `exchange.positions` and it's updated every time an event is emitted through a websocket in another class.

Is there a better way to do this like an event that gets emitted every time the set variable is updated?

Reproducible code example:

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exchange exchange = new ExchangeImpl();
        exchange.subscribePositions();
        int totalTrades = 0;
        exchange.positions.add("abc"); // initial value to execute for loop
        for (int noOfPositions = exchange.positions.size(); noOfPositions != 0; noOfPositions = exchange.positions.size()) {
            if (noOfPositions > totalTrades) {
                // some logic
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Got out of for loop");
    }
}
```

Exchange Interface:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public interface Exchange {
    Set<String> positions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    void subscribePositions();
}
```

ExchangeImpl Class:

I have created a thread that randomly adds items to the `positions` Set and empties it after a certain time. This should mimic the actual implementation of my websocket.

```
public class ExchangeImpl implements Exchange {
    @Override
    public void subscribePositions() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                int delay = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (Math.random() > 0.99) positions.add(Math.random() + "");
                if (positions.size() > 3) {
                    positions.clear();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(positions);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Added the minimal reproducible code :) I'm using ConcurrentHashMap to create the Set so it should be Thread safe but anyways, that isn't the actual problem. The actual problem is the repetitive execution of the for loop which heats up my machine. Any ideas to do this in a better way?

Comment: @BasilBourque Added some example code to reproduce, let me know if you have any ideas. Cheers!

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't see any double call. It's just checking size repeatedly, until it's equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this like an event that gets emitted every
> time the set variable is updated?

Yes exactly. Standard [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is fine. Events would be fine too, but that's basically just the observer pattern with an event bus in the middle.

Define an interface for something which listens/observes

```
interface ExchangeListener {
    void handleNewPosition(int noOfPositions, String pos);
    void handlePositionsCleared();
}
```

Exchange should be modified to add a method for adding listeners

```
interface Exchange {
    void addListener(ExchangeListener listener);
    void subscribePositions();
    /*if you ever care about unattaching:*/ void removeListener(ExchangeListener listener);
}
```

Each exchange should encapsulate the positions instead of that static mess

```
class ExchangeImpl implements Exchange {
    private final Set<String> positions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private final Set<ExchangeListener> listeners = new IdentityHashSet<>();
```

When modifications are made to the positions (i.e. within the Thread you create), iterate over the listeners and notify them of what just happened

```
for (ExchangeListener listener : listeners) {
    listener.handle__whatever___(/*any arguments*/);
}
```

In the main method, attach the listener to the exchange instead of the for-loop

```
exchange.addListener(new ExchangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleNewPosition(int noOfPositions, String pos) {
        if (noOfPositions > totalTrades) {
            // some logic
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handlePositionsCleared() {
        // Whatever
    }
});
```

Add some locking - synchronized etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Just one last thing, by implementing a listener, the main thread continues execution but my logic depends on waiting for noOfPositions to be 0 before continuing so I've added a volatile boolean variable in Main class and an empty while loop just below the addListener method that checks the boolean variable. When the noOfPositions gets 0, the listener will set the variable to false and thereby exiting the while loop. It's working fine but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @LalitTanna There are dedicated classes for that kind of thing in the `java.util.concurrent` package. `CountDownLatch` would work. Create a latch which has an initial count of 1 within `Main`. When the condition has been met, call `latch.countDown()` (will drop the value from 1 to 0). In the bit of your main method where you want to wait, call `latch.await()` (this waits until the value is 0). It achieves the same thing, but a bit more CPU efficient because the main method isn't constantly spinning in the loop.

Comment: I was just about to comment back that I found out about CountDownLatch and it worked out perfectly. Thank you so much. Earlier, I also tried synchronized block on an object but that was throwing exception as the other thread tried to call notify() on that object.